# In Ruby, when should you use self. in your classes?

Tags: ruby, self

When do you use `self.property_name` in Ruby?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use self when calling a class's mutator.  For example, this won't work:

```
class Foo
  attr_writer :bar
  def do_something
    bar = 2
  end
end
```

The problem is that 'bar = 2' creates a local variable named 'bar', rather than calling the method 'bar=' which was created by attr_writer.  However, a little `self` will fix it:

```
class Foo
  attr_writer :bar
  def do_something
    self.bar = 2
  end
end
```

`self.bar = 2` calls the method `bar=`, as desired.

You may also use self to call a reader with the same name as a local variable:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar
  def do_something
    bar = 123
    puts self.bar
  end
end
```

But it's usually better to avoid giving a local variable the same name as an accessor.

Answer (score 21):

`self` references the current object. This lends itself to many uses:

## calling a method on the current object

```
class A
    def initialize val
        @val = val
    end
    def method1
        1 + self.method2()
    end
    def method2
        @val*2
    end
end
```

Here running `A.new(1).method1()` will return `3`. The use of `self` is optional here - the following code is equivalent:

```
class A
    def initialize val
        @val = val
    end
    def method1
        1 + method2()
    end
    def method2
        @val*2
    end
end
```

`self` is not redundant for this purpose though - operator overloading makes it neccessary:

```
class A
    def initialize val
        @val = val
    end
    def [] x
        @val + x
    end
    def method1 y
        [y] #returns an array!
    end
    def method2 y
        self.[y] #executes the [] method
    end
end
```

This shows how self must be used if you want to call the current object's `[]` method.

## referencing attributes

You can generate the methods to read and write to instance variables using `attr_accessor` and co.

```
class A
    attr_accessor :val
    def initialize val
        @val = val
    end
    def increment!
        self.val += 1
    end
 end
```

Using self *is* redundant here because you can just reference the variable directly, eg. `@val`.
Using the previous class, `A.new(1).increment!` would return 2.

## method chaining

You can return self to provide a form of syntactical sugar known as chaining:

```
class A
    attr_reader :val
    def initialize val
        @val = val
    end
    def increment!
        @val += 1
        self
    end
 end
```

Here, because we are returning  the current object, methods can be chained:

```
A.new(1).increment!.increment!.increment!.val #returns 4
```

## creating class methods

You can define class methods using self:

```
class A
    def self.double x
          x*2
    end
    def self.quadruple x
        self.double(self.double(x))
    end
end
```

This will enable you to call `A.double(2) #= 4` and `A.quadruple(2) #=8`. Note that in a class method, `self` references that class because the class is the current object.

## how the value of self is determined

The current value of self in a particular method is set to the object that that method was called upon. Normally this uses the '.' notation. When you run `some_object.some_method()`, self is bound to some_object for the duration of some_method, meaning that some_method can use self in one of the ways mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Using `self` is used will reference the current object accessible within a program. Therefore, self.property is used when accessing a variable through a `attr_accessor` of some sort. In must cases, it can be used in place of @property from within an object.